# Network printer recognised but not printing

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing

I have 2 desktops, 1 of them runs win xp and has a HP Laserjet p2055d attached. My ubuntu desktop does not print though ( The one that hasn't the printer attached.) When I

```
sudo system-config-printer
```

I see the printer "up and running" yet no print jobs are sent.

What do I do?

Comment: Is this shared through the XP computer?

Comment: Yes. All the other computers running windows can access it.

Comment: If it is attached locally,with default sharing, it will be like file sharing for Windows. In this case you may have to do extra steps. When Windows shares a printer that is locally attached it creates a share file within the computer, that is unfortunately not understood by other operating systems, so although it works fine with other Windows machines, it is not meant to be compatible with other OS's.Depending on the size of the network, you could to attach the printer to the network and give it a static IP, or hostname. Or you might have to get other software for your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Can you tell me how to find it's URI in the network?

Comment: If it is a networked printer, depending on the printer, you have to go through the built in menu and find the IP settings, or print the settings. For the Windows machine if it is on a domain,from a Windows machine it will be '\\server\Computername\printers\'.
If your printer does web based configuration, and you have an IP for it. You can just type the IP into your browser. 
Check out this page, for sharing files/printers:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/153517/ubuntu-12-04-network-printing-through-windows-samba-server

You can also use HPLIP to detect a printer on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually installing the drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hpijs
```

With more recent versions of Ubuntu, hpijs is now printer-driver-hpijs, not sure when the change was made, to you may need:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip printer-driver-hpijs
```

Then delete and re-configure your printer (from system-config-printer) .